# Marker moves to map center after map is dragged

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need Google map with a Marker which will stay always in center (change its position to center) of Map when I drag map.

```
var mapcenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $coordinates ?>);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{zoom:12,center:mapcenter});
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'center_changed',function(){...});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:mapcenter,map:map});
```

This function triggered by map center change should change marker's position to map center!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
var mapcenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $coordinates ?>);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 12, center: mapcenter });
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: mapcenter, map: map });    
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'center_changed', function() {
    marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
});
```